# cannot get selected values from selectonemenu and selectmanycheckbox in jsf

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm doing testing program. So I need dynamically build GUI. But I cannot get selected values from selectonemeu and selectmanycheckbox. I know how to get values from these and used to got it.
I did it like belows

```
answerRadio[qstnCnt].setId("id" + String.valueOf(qstns.getQstn_id()) + qstnCnt);
```

and get selected value

```
String qsId = aRadio.getId().substring(2, 6);
```

But I recently changed their IDs. like belows

```
answerRadio[qstnCnt].setId("id"+ String.valueOf(qstns.getQstn_id()) + qstnCnt+rnd.nextInt());
```

and got selected value

```
String qsId = aRadio.getId().substring(2, 6);
```

So I cannot get selected values 
The reason of change ID is the components IDs are duplicated So pointing error.

Since changed IDs It not pointing error but cannot get selected values

Comment: You did not specified the reason why you cannot get selected values.